# 'They would be looking at a week Monday' - what does this mean?

Tags: meaning, informal-language, australian-english

They would be looking at a week Monday - does that work for you?

Does it mean?

1. I should be available on Monday next week.

or

2. I should be available on any working day in the next week.

Comment: Your question does not match its Title.  Does it matter when you received the email?  Or are you just asking about the use of "at a week Monday" (which, by the way, in AmE makes no sense at all.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In British English, 'a week Monday' means one week after the next Monday.  I'd be surprised if Australians were using it any differently.

So assuming you received the email on Saturday 4th July, they want to interview you on Monday 13th July.  However, you should still email them back to confirm that this is the correct date.

Comment: Worth noting: I’m American and I’d never heard that construction before, and though I did suspect it meant what you say it means, I was not confident in that suspicion. So using this phrasing may confuse Americans.

Answer (score 1):

This sentenced confused me at first but I realized it is just missing a period or a comma in between "week" and "Monday". "They would be looking at a week" seems like the answer to a previous question like "How long will it take them to do ___?" And the second part is asking if Monday is a good day to start.

Comment: Here is the original paragraph -Good news, xxx would like to fly you over from Australia for an interview.  They would be looking at a week Monday - does that work for you? My question is are they expecting me to be available on Monday or they will start the process on Monday?

Comment: It's not exactly clear what that sentence means. It probably means that you would be gone for a week and you would leave Monday.  Its not clear what "week" or "Monday" are referring to and that is further made confusing by a possibly missing comma or period. It could mean something else. I would ask them to clarify what they are saying with that sentence.